# Issues with deploying React based app on Railway

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, deployment

I was moving my fullstack app (React + Express) from Heroku.
The problem was that React app has to be built for running (also has to install required dependencies), but on git we usually store only raw source code.

A common structure for fullstack projects:

[image]

Heroku has the option to run scripts after deployment with a special script in the `package.json` file:

```
"heroku-postbuild": "npm install --prefix client && npm run build --prefix client"
```

But I didn't find a similar ability on Railway.

So my solution is:

1. Remove the build folder from the `.gitignore` file
2. Build react app with npm run build
3. Add all to git repository
4. [Deploy on Railway via Git Repo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dKE0j.png)
5. [Do not forget to add environment variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e5jIF.png)
6. [Create domain name to have access via public internet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BfDbP.png)
7. Be happy!

I had some problems with this, so I am sharing the easiest solution for others.

Comment: What did you use for "Start command"? I set up my Express server fine, and now wanting to move my React front-end, but Railway needs a start command and I don't know what to put there...

Comment: @Barraka according to docs https://docs.railway.app/deploy/deployments#start-command Railway automatically configures the start command based on the code being deployed. So I don't have anything in that field. If it's not your case, you can try to insert there commands you've used during dev by hand (inspect your package.json files). For example in my case it will be node server/server.js && cd client && npm start
Where we firstly start the server, than go to folder with client and start it. But it depends on files structures and tech you use

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By selecting a project on Railway, and going to its settings, you would find a field named `Build Command`. There you can add your build commands. For example, in your specific case, this should work:

```
cd client && npm install && npm run build && cd .. && npm i
```

If it does not work, look at your project structure and adapt the command. Currently, the field is there:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Go to the project setting and set your build command. I've fixed it this way- https://prnt.sc/OnYPp1Q5-Uze

```
npm run build
```

Answer (score 0):

Without changing anything in your package.json all you need to do is fill "build command" in railway to `npm run heroku-postbuild`